# Is it possible to view cameras that are on a different network?

Tags: network, networking

I work in a manufacturing plant that has several cameras that we use in production. Our camera server just went down and I'm trying to find a way to still view the cameras till a new server can be put in place.

The problem that I'm running into is that the cameras are all on their own network which is separate from the network that everything else is on. The camera server had dual NICs to accommodate this and see all the cameras and send that to all the other computers on the regular network.

Is there a way that I can view these cameras even though they are on a separate network?

Example: My computer IP is like 172.13.25.100

Camera Outside IP like 192.168.1.100

Is there a way for me to view that camera from my computer?

Comment: You need a router to connect between these two networks, but it sounds like this was intentionally designed not to allow you to do that.  If you're the network admin, you should carefully consider the performance and security impacts of connecting these networks before you do.  If you're not the admin, that's who you should be talking to.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I don't really want to connect the networks. I think that I have a temporary workaround going in place right though. A temp server to act as a camera server until the new one comes in. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: A) This looks like a server routing problem instead of a network infrastructure problem; server problems are off-topic here. B) If you think this really is a network infrastructure problem, please [add more information](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/network-engineering-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

Add a route to 192.168/16 subnet via your current gateway - use `ipconfig /all` ( assuming Windows ) to see your gateway, then use `tracert <IP>` to see if you can pass.

It may be another router that handles the route from 172.13.25.100 to 192.168.1.100, but your gateway should know about that. You can add any number of routes in the network settings for your connection, but don’t remove the default route.